# Can I add a CSS sheet at another place than inside the <head>?

Tags: css

I'm editor on a kind of wiki. I don't have a full access to the web server.

The only thing I can do is adding html inside pages.

So, i've learned that I can do this :

```
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
  </head>
```

Or this :

```
  <head><style>
       my css copy pasted here
  </style></head>
```

But I have no access to the < head>

I'd like to do something like this :

```
  <div>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
  </div>
```

Just that way doesn't work. I'm almost sure that the thing I want to do is not possible, but before giving up with this idea, I wanted to check here

Comment: Which HTML tags does the wiki send to the browser without turning < into &lt; and > into &gt;? That will determine whether it's possible to do what you want to do.

Comment: According to the W3C spec for HTML4, no, you need to place them in the head. http://w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-LINK

Comment: I guess it would help if you could tell which HTML/XHTML-version the wiki is using, so it would be easier to determine what is allowed and what's not.

Answer (score 1):

the `<style>` tag can be used in `<body>`, too, so you can put a `<style type="text/css">` in the body.

```
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
    css goes here
    </style>
</body>
```

However, remember that where the CSS is placed has an effect on how it cascades. You might have to watch out for that.

Also remember that although most browsers will accept this, it's invalid HTML, not allowed by HTML5.

Comment: This is certainly not true for HTML5. It's not allowed to use the `<style>`-tag within the `<body>`-tag. Even though most browsers will accept it, it's invalid HTML.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Ah. Right. Fixing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use styles pretty much anywhere in your HTML. Just be aware that some locations take precedence over others. 
http://stevenclark.com.au/2008/07/27/external-embedded-and-inline-css/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery http://www.rickardnilsson.net/post/2008/08/02/Applying-stylesheets-dynamically-with-jQuery.aspx

Comment: You do not need jQuery to do this at all and @Slava's will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's valid in HTML5 but not in HTML4. I think the biggest risk (other than it being ignored by a browser) is the flash of style being applied as the page is loaded.

Comment: No. You cannot use the stylesheet link element because it contains the rel attribute. That will make it invalid.

Comment: @Rob - As I mentioned, in HTML5 it's valid. In HTML4x it's not. Recommended? No. Unorthodox? Yes.

Comment: No it is not valid in HTML5. See the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot use the link element inside the body when it contains "rel".](http://developers.whatwg.org/semantics.html#the-link-element) You can only use that in the head.

Comment: No, in HTML4 it can only appear in the head regardless: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-LINK

Comment: @TheZ - Please see my link to the HTML5 spec. It will work in all browsers regardless of doctype.

Comment: @TheZ - Did you wait till just last year to start using CSS 2.1? That's when it was finalized. These standards are based on implementation. Otherwise, you are waiting 10 years or more to start using HTML5 while the rest of us have been using it for quite a while now.

Comment: While using the specs _in addition to_ legal HTML4 is fine and dandy, I wouldn't tell people to use it when it directly conflicts with the currently allowed rules.

Comment: Curiously, the W3C microdata spec disagrees with the WHATWG version. It says ["If a link element has an itemprop attribute, the rel attribute may be omitted."](http://dev.w3.org/html5/md/#content-models). *May*, not *Must*. This would appear to allow `<link>` with a `rel` attribute to be valid in body if it also had an `itemprop` attribute. I suspect this is not intentional.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this directly, but there is a trick.

You can dynamically add CSS-file with javascript:

```
<body>

    <script>
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.setAttribute('rel',  'stylesheet');
        link.setAttribute('href', 'mystyle.css');
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    </script>

</body>
```

But consider it a hack, i would not recommend to use this in production. You should ask for more authority if it is your direct line of work.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of HTML5 you can add a style tag into a div tag, if the style tag sports the "scoped" attribute. The W3-validator does not yet reflect this change.

And no matter whether or not this stuff validates, all browsers I tested will render both inline and linked styles when added to the body.

Yes, your challenge will be to find a way to prevent the wiki software from changing the tag brackets into html entities.

Comment: I guess it could get tricky with the `scoped`-attribute. I don't think that any current browser supports it and if (in any future version) the layout could break, as `scoped` is used for a specific element and it's children.

Comment: Not a single browser I tested trips over current use of the scoped attribute. The only thing tripping over haphazerdly placed style, link, and script tags, is the W3 validator (and similar strict tools).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. What I meant is. If the OP doesn't use this attribute as it's intent is and some browsers may support it in the near future, his layout could be displayed in a different way than expected/rendered before.